# How to terminate a nested for loop by clicking a button?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, button

This is the nested loop in Visual Basic which loops through the numbers in an array.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To test.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine(test(x))
            For y As Integer = 0 To test.Length - 1
                Console.WriteLine(test(x) & test(y))
                 Next
               Next
```

I want to terminate the loop by clicking a button. Since all the processing power goes to the loop, the button is greyed out. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use something like a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` or `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` and check to see whether the task/worker has been cancelled on every loop iteration.  Multithreading is a fairly broad topic, but [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should get you started.

Comment: Or TPL, which is more modern approach.

Comment: Maybe even this, a more generic article on [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First add a boolean

```
Dim done As Boolean
```

Now add a background worker to the form. Double click on backgroundWorker and add the following code under the backgroundWorker

```
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As        System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork


For x As Integer = 0 To test.Length - 1
        Console.WriteLine(test(x))
        For y As Integer = 0 To test.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine(test(x) & test(y))
             Next
            If done = true then exit sub
           Next
         If done = true then exit sub
End Sub
```

Now add a button to start the loop. This button sets boolean to false and runs the backgroundWorker.

```
Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
done = False 
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Finally add a button to stop the loop. This button sets boolean to true.

```
Private Sub ButtonStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
done = True
End SUb
```